# Ring Homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}_m$ to $\mathbb{Z}_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Suppose $R$ is a ring homomorphism from $\Bbb{Z}_m$ to $\Bbb{Z}_n$ , prove that if $R(1) = a$ then $(a^2)=a$. Also show, its converse is not true.

The first part goes like this :

$R(1) = a , R(1\cdot 1) = a$,

$R(1) \cdot R(1) = a$   { since R is a ring homomorphism }

so , $a\cdot a = a$ or $(a^2)=a$ ;

Kindly help me with the converse part....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In $\mathbb{Z}/6$, $3^2=3$.  But, we cannot have a map $\mathbb{Z}/5\to \mathbb{Z}/6$ such that $f(1)=3$, because $5\cdot 3=3$ in $\mathbb{Z}/6$, but $5\cdot 1=0$ in $\mathbb{Z}/5$.

Comment: is it correct to say this like this : assume R(1)=3 , consider R(1+(-1)) = R(1) + R(-1) which is R(1) + 4 R(1) = 15(mod 6) = 3.
thus R(0) = 3 but that"s not possible as R should send "0" element to the "0"th element.. is this right ?

Comment: @RohitDuggal Yes.